# What to do in case of unexpected torpor?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

I have a player whose character had fall in torpor by damage, so i was wondering if there are some alternatives to wake up him.

We are using Vampire Dark Ages 20th Anniversary Edition.

Comment: More details, such as the generation of the vampire in torpor in your comment on 8t88's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105179), perhaps what kind of damage he has taken (not just the latest damage, but all damage), might help craft a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a group of WoD players in Moscow, Russia, that uses strongly house-ruled oWoD rules for tabletop sessions, but also plays LARP with the same characters under slightly different rules. As they play series of games, they use the same characters over and over. For various reasons, I did not play with them myself, but if I am not mistaken in what I have heard from their GM, they have special rules to awaken a character from Torpor, as it really sucks to lose your seemingly immortal character just because you got an extra bullet in your kidney.

Allies of a torpid vampire have to come and give her some amount of Blood Points -- I do not know (or do not remember) how many exactly, but it is not that important. Obviously, this leads to a Blood Bond as per normal Blood Bond rules.

Set the amount based on how strict are you generally with giving blood away. Could be as small as 1 BP if you are not strict, and as many as 10 BP if you are, this variable only depends on your own opinion.

The need of a higher-Generation ally to help could make sense, but it depends on how hard do you want the encounter to be. This group of LARP players has an additional difficulty of having to locate the torpid body of the char, so it helps if one of the group members has fallen, but not in a case of Total Party Kill.

Are you ready to dedicate a session or a few to finding a way to resurrect a char? Or do you want it to be just as easy as "revive your ally by giving your hand to him/her to get up", as in many online computer games?

*Set the difficulty based on your preferences, on your playstyle.* Probably discuss it with your group.

If your characters are into Thaumaturgy, you could also try to develop a ritual, but I am not giving any suggestions because I have zero experience in designing rituals as of now.

Answer (score -3):

In Vampire-The Reqiuem, you can use Blood of someone with 2 Points more Blood Potency to wake him up. So you group could get into debt with one Vampire of a lower Generation, and: First blood Ties Step is also made.
This might be the Start for an Interesting Plot for the Torpid Vampires Player.

Comment: It's a good way to end torpor, but, the problem is that they need to find someone with 4th generation at least. He's in really trouble

Comment: Okay, I just thought Problems add to the Plot (in our group), but I do not know your Campaign. Sorry

Comment: Vampire - The Requiem has an other way of determining the power level of vampires. I don't think that's a good idea to directly translate to a Vampire - Dark Ages question.

Comment: @SliferDragon Are you trying to awake a 5th Generation character?

Comment: @Nuscheltier Actually, even though systems are different, there is even a [series of books dedicated to transitioning content between *Chronicles of Darkness* and oWoD](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Translation_Guide).